WebStorm - HTML class selector previews
I recently switched over from VSCode to WebStorm, and I'm having trouble finding how to preview CSS selector chaining.
The specific selector I am chaining in this example is:
.header-container {
  &.short-header {
    
  }
}

Where I'm hoping to see a reflection of header-container short-header
VSCode example:

In WebStorm I've tried Cmd + Y / Opt + Space for the usage panel as well as Cmd hovering which don't show exactly what I am going for.
Cmd hover

Cmd+Y / Opt+Space

Any insight is appreciated, thank you!

Doesn't look like it recognizes the new nested CSS syntax. Maybe there's an add-on?

@ralph.m it's SCSS.

As far as I'm getting the issue and how it currently works in WebStorm -- it's not yet implemented for nested Sass/SCSS (or works incorrectly).
Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get updates on any progress:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-61343
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-64024
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50552

